# Adding a Non aggregate column in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to add column named 'Number3'  in the below query.But it is a non aggregate column which if added to select statement and group by clause ,changes the result.

How do i get the same result and add the column named 'Number3'in the query  without adding it to group by clause??

```
select distinct [Name], 
max([ArchiveDT]) as [ArchiveDT],
Number1,
Number2
FROM Table
where ArchiveDT>=dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0) and
  ArchiveDT<dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
  and [Name] is not null
group by [Name] ,Number1,Number2
```

Comment: What is the nature of the `Number3` column? Does it always contain the same data for every combination of `Name,Number1,Number2`? If not, *by what logic* should we/SQL Server select *which* value to use in that column?

Comment: And add some sample data (input, expected output). It makes your question more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query :

```
 SELECT  A.[Name] , A.[ArchiveDT] , A.Number1,A.Number2,O.NUmber3
 FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[ArchiveMessages_ACARS] O
 JOIN 
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name],MAX([ArchiveDT]) as [ArchiveDT],
        Number1,Number2
    FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[ArchiveMessages_ACARS]
    WHERE ArchiveDT>=dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0) and
       ArchiveDT<dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
       and [Name] is not null
    GROUP BY [Name] ,Number1,Number2
  ) A ON A.[Common_value] = O.[Common_value]
```

Comment: this doesn't returns all columns.Error encoutered:-Ambiguous column name 'Name'

Comment: Thank you.This serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column to an aggregate query.
You have either to add it to `GROUP BY`.
If this does not suit your expected results, you will have to use an aggregate function.
Like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN` or `MAX` if you wish it to appear anyway.

In your example it could give something like :

```
select distinct [Name], 
max([ArchiveDT]) as [ArchiveDT],
Number1,
Number2,
MAX(Number3)
FROM [SAEI].[dbo].[ArchiveMessages_ACARS]
where ArchiveDT>=dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0) and
  ArchiveDT<dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
  and [Name] is not null
group by [Name] ,Number1,Number2
```

Comment: i dont want to use max function with number 3

Comment: `MAX` is just an example, you can use whatever the aggregate function you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a derived table, but it would only work if you have a unique identifier in the derived table, an example would be:

```
SELECT          A.*,
                B.NUMBER3
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT [NAME]                              , 
                MAX([ARCHIVEDT]) AS [ARCHIVEDT]     ,
                NUMBER1                             ,
                NUMBER2
FROM            [SAEI].[DBO].[ARCHIVEMESSAGES_ACARS]
WHERE           ARCHIVEDT>=DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1), 0) 
AND             ARCHIVEDT<DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND             [NAME] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY        [NAME] ,
                [NUMBER1],
                [NUMBER2]
)   AS A
 INNER JOIN     [SAEI].[DBO].[ARCHIVEMESSAGES_ACARS] AS B ON B.[NAME] = A.
[NAME]
```